# Js take elements between 2 values (array)

Tags: javascript

How i do for take elements between 4 and 7 in my array ?

```
var mymain = [ 
 ['1', 'ooo'],
 ['2', 'salade'],
 ['3', 'fraise'],
 ['4', 'pomme'],
 ['5', 'banane'],
 ['6', 'tomate'],
 ['7', 'cerise'],
 ['9', 'melon'],
];
```

i need pomme banane tomate and cerise .

Sorry to my bad english . 
Thank you for your futur help

Comment: `mymain[3]`, `mymain[4]`, `mymain[5]`, `mymain[6]`

Answer (score 0):

Try `array.splice(index,howmany)`:

```
var arr = mymain.splice(3,4); //  result is an Array
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/HnWNm/)

Comment: Why do you splice the array?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [array `slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Because of your data structure, you can directly get the zero-based array indices from the one-based ids by subtracting 1. Then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the result to strings you want:

```
mymain
 .slice(4-1, 7) // the indices 3, 4, 5, and 6
 .map(function(item) { return item[1]; }) // get the string for each item
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for dynamic operation (not based on assuming index), then this is the way to go.

```
var mymain = [ 
 ['1', 'ooo'],
 ['2', 'salade'],
 ['3', 'fraise'],
 ['4', 'pomme'],
 ['5', 'banane'],
 ['6', 'tomate'],
 ['7', 'cerise'],
 ['9', 'melon'],
];


for(var i =0; i<mymain.length; i++){

    if(4 <= mymain[i][0] && 7 >= mymain[i][0]){
        alert(mymain[i][1]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mymain = [ 
 ['1', 'ooo'],
 ['2', 'salade'],
 ['3', 'fraise'],
 ['4', 'pomme'],
 ['5', 'banane'],
 ['6', 'tomate'],
 ['7', 'cerise'],
 ['9', 'melon'],
];

alert(mymain[3][1]+" "+mymain[4][1]+" "+mymain[5][1]+" and "+mymain[6][1]);
```